# Как запустить видео (HLS) на Android?

Tags: android, http, streaming

Имеется ссылка вида `http:/.../rossiya-1/index.m3u8?token=secret`.

Нужно воспроизвести эту трансляцию на Android-устройствах от 4.0. ExoPlayer сразу признаем непригодным.

При таком кодом я получаю сообщение *"нельзя проиграть это видео"*:

```
Myplayer = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_player_video_view);
if (linkOnResources != null) {
    Logi.d("linkOfresources not null");
    Myplayer.requestFocus();
    *//Тут получаю ссылку в виде строки и передаю в setVideoURI*
    Myplayer.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(linkOnResources.getHls()));
    Myplayer.start();
```

Понятного мне решения найти не удалось. Склоняюсь к применению *Vitamo*.

Возможно, кто-то сталкивался с HLS и может хотя бы посоветовать направление, в котором нужно двигаться, чтобы решить задачу?

Comment: А почему вы написали "ExoPlayer сразу признаем непригодным."?

Answer (score 1):

Взято отсюда
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

> HTTP/HTTPS live streaming draft protocol:

- MPEG-2 TS media files only
- Protocol version 3 (Android 4.0 and above)
- Protocol version 2 (Android 3.x)
- Not supported before Android 3.0

Т.е. направление такое, HLS на Андроид 4.0 в общем работает, но нужно уточнить кодек, если не поддерживается, то проигрывать сторонним приложением.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, проблема  была не во мне. Проблема с авторизацией на стороне сервера оказалась(403 код).Через 3g получилось и запустить через родное и через встроенное.